# Can't edit my network profile without it syncing to my oldest account

Tags: support, network-profile, profile-sync

On Stack Exchange, not this Meta, my profile keeps syncing with my oldest profile, which is my Sci Fi and Fantasy profile.

How can I fix this, or is it impossible to stop it from syncing? How can I stop the narrative I have on the Sci-Fi site from syncing to my Stack Exchange network profile?

Comment: While editing your profile, do you click *"Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts"* button?

Comment: @hims056 not relevant, it does not update the network profile.